# AlphabetIndexer with Custom Adapter managed by LoaderManager

Tags: android, adapter, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I am trying to implement `AlphabetIndexer` with Custom Adapter like this

[AlphabetIndexer with Custom Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115920/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter)

My class ContactsCursorAdapter extends `SimpleCursorAdapter` and implements `SectionIndexer`
and I am using a `LoaderManager` to manage my adapter's cursor so i have overridden the `swapCursor()` method like the second answer to the example above indicates.

```
public class ContactsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter 
    implements SectionIndexer{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext; 

    private AlphabetIndexer mAlphaIndexer;

    public ContactsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return mAlphaIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return mAlphaIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return mAlphaIndexer.getSections();
    }

    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c) {
        // Create our indexer
        if (c != null) {
            mAlphaIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME),
                " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        }
        return super.swapCursor(c);
    }
}
```

However, this errors out if I set my listview to fastScrollEnabled = true

getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);

in my class ContactsCursorLoaderListFragment which extends `ListFragment` and implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks .

Here is the stack trace:

```
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sendit/com.sendit.ContactManager}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.sendit.ContactsCursorAdapter.getSections(ContactsCursorAdapter.java:222)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.widget.FastScroller.getSectionsFromIndexer(FastScroller.java:507)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.widget.FastScroller.init(FastScroller.java:269)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.widget.FastScroller.<init>(FastScroller.java:155)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.widget.AbsListView.setFastScrollEnabled(AbsListView.java:1144)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.sendit.LoaderCursor$ContactsCursorLoaderListFragment.onActivityCreated(LoaderCursor.java:107)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:847)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4474)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
04-25 01:37:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  ... 11 more
```

after the `setFastScrollEnabled()` method gets called it calls the custom adapter's `getSections()` method which is where it crashes.

```
public class LoaderCursor extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            ContactsCursorLoaderListFragment list = new ContactsCursorLoaderListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class ContactsCursorLoaderListFragment extends ListFragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        ContactsCursorAdapter mAdapter;
        Cursor mCursor;
        String mCurFilter;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            populateContactList();

            // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
            // or start a new one.
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
            //lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);
            lv.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_divider));

        }       

        // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
        final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID, };

        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created. This
            // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
            // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
            // currently filtering.
            Uri baseUri;
            if (mCurFilter != null) {
                baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
            } else {
                baseUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            }

            // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
            // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
            String selection = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + 
                " NOTNULL) AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) 
                AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, selection, null, sortOrder);

        }

        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) { 
            // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
            // old cursor once we return.)
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        }

        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
            // above is about to be closed. We need to make sure we are no
            // longer using it.
            mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }

        /**
        * Populate the contact list
        */
        private void populateContactList() {

            // start mappings
            String[] from = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contactInfo };

            // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
            mAdapter = new ContactsCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),    
                R.layout.contact_manager, null, from, to);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }   

    }
}
```

And if I comment the `setFastScrollEnabled()` call, then it does not error out, but I do not see the `AlphabetIndexer` working.

Does this need to be implemented differently because my custom adapter is set in a `ListFragment` and not a `ListActivity`?

Does anyone have suggestions about how to make this all work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I finally got this to work.  Here's how i did it:

I added:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);
```

to the `onLoadFinished()` method after the new cursor was swapped in like so

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) { 
 // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
 // old cursor once we return.)
 mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

 ListView lv = getListView();
 lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
 lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);

}
```

consequently these three statements were removed from the `onActivityCreated()` method of my custom `ListFragment`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just make your `getSections` method return an empty list if there's no data instead of throwing a null pointer exception?

Comment: Yes it would be a good idea to return an empty list if the data is not available, however the getSections() should be called after the cursor is swapped in since this is implementing a CursorLoader.

Comment: just adding my two cents here: this only works if you never set the setListShown(false); for the loading to appear. Otherwise the fastscroll will never appear until you refresh the cursor with new data (diferent than the actual)