# How to create a activity and xml file same as our default contacts UI in android?

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a activity same as our default contacts in android, where there are alphabets for searching the list and a search EditText for searching the contacts. I get the contacts from webservice and I want to show it same like how our contacts look in android.
If any one knows any better tutorial or solution are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

```
where there are alphabets for searching the list
```

That's a `ListView` that has `setFastScrollEnabled()` set to true along with a `SectionIndexer`. Setting [Fast scroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled%28boolean%29) to true enables a scroll bar, also known as thumb scroller. For showing sections (e.g., alphabets), you'll have to use a [SectionIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html)

**Edit**: To be precise, an AlphabetIndexer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for same?

Comment: Yes, there are several. Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

http://www.danielespinetti.it/2011/11/android-snippet-code-android-listview.html